# Unable to clone mSATA disk in my W530

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, clone, acronis-trueimage, msata

I recently bought a used W530 from eBay, which is in good shape. It has a 240GB mSATA and two other disks. It runs on Win 7 pro 64bit.

I used its recovery media disk to restore the computer to its factory state and reformatted the two other disks.

Now I have installed some software on the computer and everything sits on mSATA, which is recognized as C: drive.

I also installed Acronis True Image Home 2011 on this machine, I am hoping to clone the mSATA drive for backup. However, Acronis is only able to list mSATA as C drive, but greys it out, and I am unable to select it as a disk for cloning.

Does anyone know why? Looked around and cannot find a solution to this.

Thanks so much for any help!

**Update**

Here is the screenshot showing W530's disks shown in Macrium 5. It can seen that the C drive is not even shown.

[image]

The following is the screenshot showing that the C drive is not selectable. The screenshot lists mSATA as Disk 2.

[image]

Comment: If it is for backup, I would recommend to make an image, not a clone.

Comment: whs, thanks so much for chiming in! Which tool do you recommend for this?

Comment: Microsoft finally packaged a reasonable backup solution with Win7. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked the question which tools I would recommend for imaging the C partition. Here is what I recommend:

A. In a normal Windows 7 installation you have to image the C partition and the 100MB System Partition which contains the bootmgr. Usually there is also a recovery partition which I would image at least once.

B. If you ever want to recover from the image, you need a recovery medium which can be a CD or a USB flash drive. I will specify what to use.

D. Imaging programs - there is a vast choice of imaging programs, but I found 2 solutions that work very well and are easy to use. They are also fast and reliable.

D1. Free Macrium Version 5 (not version 6 which is not free) is my preferred solution. Here is **[a tutorial I made](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73828-imaging-free-macrium.html?ltr=I)** where you find all the information required. Since this is easily overlooked in the tutorial, **[I give you my link](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=475A0A48CA6D4035&id=475A0A48CA6D4035%211812)** from where you can download the .iso for the recovery CD/flash drive. Just burn that .iso to a CD or Flash drive and for recovery you boot the PC with that medium. You can, of course, produce that recovery medium yourself from within Macrium.

D2. Another easy way to make an image is via an elevated command prompt. The command is:

**wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:X: -include:C: -AllCritical -quiet**

Where 'X' is the address of the device to where you want to place the image. The '-AllCritical' parameter will make sure that the 100MB System Partition is automatically imaged with the C partition. This is unlike solution D1 where you have to explicitely select that 100MB partition to be imaged with C. The recovery from the image you can initiate with any Windows 7 installation/recovery disk.

Should you ever want to make an image of a data partition, you can use the same command, but you must leave the '-AllCritical' parameter off - else you would also image C and the whole 9 yards with that data partition.

Comment: whs. thanks so much for such long and detailed response. I have Macrium  5 and I installed it. But I am unable to see the C drive, which is listed as Disk 2 in the screenshot with Acronis. Best.

Comment: In my Acronis screenshot, I noticed that my C drive (Disk 2) is tagged as GPT and I did some research. It seems that is the reason giving me headache. Do you know of any way of cloning or imaging the C drive? Thanks!!!

Comment: Try the command prompt command. But it is strange that Macrium does not work. I have imaged Windows 8.1 (GPT) with it. Download and burn the CD  from the iso on my OneDrive that I linked and see whether you can image with that. This CD (iso) is a full Macrium program and can do the same as the installed program.

Comment: I eventually bought Acronis 2015, which can handles backup of GPT disks. Thanks!